# data caching in supabase client

Tags: caching, supabase, supabase-js

I'm using the supabase js client in an app.

Initial data fetching takes an expected 300 - 400ms or so. After that, I sometimes fetch a part of the same data again (I could do this all with my frontend store, but sometimes the data complexity is quite deep and a fetch is just simpler).
[image: Simplified schema]

Using the simplified schema above, I fetch orgs, with nested groups, with nested groups members. I fetch members nested under orgs. Later on, I sometimes need all the groupsMembers of a member, for that I do a new fetch.

**Note: I understand that there are other ways to achieve this: Query the groupsMembers directly under members as well, or write a helper function in the frontend store to get these. My question is not about these other methods, but rather about how the supabase client works.**

I have the feeling that I get very fast fetching in those cases. I get the feeling that the supabase client does this: It keeps its own cache in the frontend that it can query instantly, as long as its sure that no new data needs to be fetched.

**Is that the case? If that is the case, can I simply use the supabase client as a full blown frontend store? Are there any limitations in doing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supabase-js client library does not cache anything, and it will make a network request every time you perform a `select()`.